# Get dimensions to transform image to a maximum value

Tags: php

I need to get some dimensions to display images.

I want to display the image in a maximum pixel-size for the longest side of the image.
So, if the maximum length should be 1000px, I have to check if the height or the width is bigger. After that I resize the dimensions in the correct proportions.
If the image dimensions are smaller then 1000px, nothing should happen.

This is my solution, which already works. But I don't feel well with it. Is there a smarter solution?

```
dimensions(1000);

function dimensions($limit) {           
    if ($width >= $height) {
        if ($width < $limit) $limit = $width;
        $factor = $width / $limit;
    }
    else {
        if ($height < $limit) $limit = $height;
        $factor = $height / $limit;
    }   
    $new_width = $width / $factor;
    $new_height = $height / $factor;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well my example code:

```
function dimensions($limit) { 
    $tmp = max($width, $height);
    $limit = min($limit, $tmp);
    $factor = $tmp / $limit;

    $new_width = $width / $factor;
    $new_height = $height / $factor;
}
```