# Calculating value depending on width or height of an image

Tags: php

I want to check if the height or the width of an image is bigger. Depending on that, a maximum value is defined. If it is a landscape image `$limit = 1000;` if it is a vertical format `$limit = 600;`

After this the image can be scaled correctly (maximum width 1000px or 600px depending on the format of the image). If the image is smaller than that, the image values are used. (Just downscaling).

Depending on [Get dimensions to transform image to a maximum value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28788075/get-dimensions-to-transform-image-to-a-maximum-value) I don't know how to realize these two different limit values:

```
$tmp = max($width, $height); # give me the bigger value
$limit = min($limit, $tmp); # if image dimension is lower, take that value
$factor = $tmp / $limit; # calculate factor to get the new dimensions

$new_width = $width / $factor;
$new_height = $height / $factor;
```

So this works great if there is only one limit-value (ie. 1000).

I just need the values, no real transforming of the image...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`min(1,` is only needed if you want only reduce big images and not resize smaller images:

```
$maxWidth = 1000;
$maxWidthIfVertical = 600;
$factor = $width > $height ? min(1, $maxWidth / $width) : min(1, $maxWidthIfVertical / $width);
$newWidth = $width * $factor;
$newHeight = $height * $factor;
```

Caution with this method, see the examples I added here: http://jsfiddle.net/Wornet/z3z6fcr3/4/ I think it's not realy what you want.

So I recommand this (limit 1000 in width, 800 in height):
http://jsfiddle.net/Wornet/z3z6fcr3/6/

Comment: Not sure if there is a misunderstanding. If there is an image 4000x3000, it should be converted to 1000x750 (max width 1000 and 750 calculated to keep the same ratio). If the image is 3000x4000, the result should be 600x800 (max width(!) 600 and calculated height of 800. An image 400x300 should be kept, as it is too small.

Comment: OK, just are you sure it's pertinent since you will get image with width bigger than 1000 (in landscape) and height bigger than 600 (in vertical format). So my first code: http://jsfiddle.net/Wornet/z3z6fcr3/ (recommanded for a slider, gallery, etc.) Or what you ask: http://jsfiddle.net/Wornet/z3z6fcr3/2/ (I do not recommand this approch).